# What is the meaning of "I'm in a rhubarb of a pickle of a jam here"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?I know every words in the sentence but can't figure out the meaning of it.

> Homer, I'm in a rhubarb of a pickle of a jam here. I was all set to go
>   off on vacation when I get called up for jury duty. Oh, it's a corker
>   of a case.

Comment: Please allow at least a day or two before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away (and indeed you got an excellent one right away). For info about why this is helpful, please see [“Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)”](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Comment: Hotdog! I mustard the courage to relish the opportunity to ketchup on the answers to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phrase combines a variety of idiom and slang to make a very evocative phrase.

> "In a jam" means "In a difficult situation."
>
> "In a pickle" means "In a mess" or "In trouble."
>
> "Rhubarb" means "Nonsense" (British) or "Quarrel" (American).

So put all together we have:

> "I'm in a nonsensical, messy, difficult situation."

or

> "I'm in a quarrelsome, messy, difficult situation."

Since the quote appears to be from The Simpsons, I would assume the second one.

Comment: Would you say it in your daily life or it was made up especially from words which are related to fruit in order to get it sound funny?

Comment: It is comically "over the top". Compare Woody Allen's *It's a travesty of a mockery of a sham of a mockery of a travesty of two mockeries of a sham* from the movie *Bananas* (1971).

Comment: @Dash It's a funny, creative phrase used in one episode of a television comedy. It exaggerates a folksy style of expression heard in the American Midwest. I have never heard it in daily life. It almost sounds like it belongs in a song.

Comment: Americans will commonly say "I'm in jam" to mean "I'm in trouble". "I'm in a pickle" is, I think, mostly obsolete but a similar meaning. I've never heard "rhubarb" used in such a context, I see it in a dictionary, maybe it's mostly obsolete or maybe it's regional. Anyway, few would put all three together in one sentence. Any one would be a normal statement. Combining them is a humorous way of saying the problem is really serious.

Comment: "I'm in a pickle" is the British version of "I'm in a jam". It's common in certain parts of Britain, while "I'm in a jam" is uncommon all over Britain.